# How can i sort table records in SQL Server 2014 Management Studio by Alphabetical?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many record in one table :

```
1 dog
2 cat 
3 lion
```

I want to recreate table or sort data with this Alphabetical order :

```
1 cat
2 dog
3 lion
```

Table 1

```
Id      int             Unchecked
name    nvarchar(50)    Checked
```

Comment: Hint:  `order by name`.

Comment: SELECT name FROM tblname ORDER BY name ASC;

Comment: I want to recreate table not for Temporary time.

Comment: Then you need another table unless records are limited for sure.

Comment: and when this table gets a new record - does everything have to be shuffled around again to correct the numeric column? What you're asking for doesn't make sens. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Sami answer works ,  but it works just for three column , not many column and not alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create another table from your table :

```
CREATE TABLE T1 
( ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
NAME NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES ('Dog'),('Cat'),('Lion');

SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()OVER (ORDER BY NAME ASC) ID, NAME INTO T2 FROM T1 ORDER BY NAME ASC;
```

Comment: Please explain to the poster what this code is doing and why it answers his question. Code-only answers aren't terribly educational IMHO.

Comment: @alroc Wish that all users on SO say what you say , but ... No there is a few .

Comment: Thanks, but it works just for three column , not many column and not alphabetical order.

Comment: @nasr What you mean ? I answer your question

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to sort the table data, use `Order by`

```
Select * from table_1 order by Name
```

If you want to change the Id's as well according to alphabetical order, create a new table and move the records to the new table by order.

```
SELECT   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name ) AS Id, name
INTO   newTable
FROM   table_1
```

Comment: No, I want to recreate table such as Sami answer, but for a 1000 data.

Comment: Yes, the second query recreates the table.

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution that is short, easy and works like a charm. Just delete the Id afterwards and you are fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your database, the order of the records as they were inserted into the table does not necessarily dictate the order in which they're returned when queried. Nor does the ordering of a clustered key. There may be situations in which you *appear to* always get the same ordering of your results, but that is not guaranteed and may change at any time.

If the results of a query **must** be a specific order, then you **must** specify that ordering with an `ORDER BY` clause in your query (`ORDER BY [Name] ASC` in this particular case).

I understand, based upon your comments above, that you don't *want* this to be the answer. But this is how SQL Server (and any other relational database) works. If order matters, you specify that upon querying data *from* the system, not when inserting data into it.

Comment: No, I want to recreate table such as Sami answer, but for a 1000 data.

Comment: @nasr And I'm saying that there's no point in doing so because the only way you'll get query output in a particular order is by using Order By.